# Axios get request is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

In react native the get request is not working. Can anyone help me here?

```
export const getDashboardService = async (params, callback, errorCallback) => {
const url = ServerConstants.serviceMethods.baseUrl + params.userId;
try {
    let res = await axios.get(
        url,
        {
            headers: {
                ...ServerConstants.serviceHeaderParameters,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${params.token}`
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(res);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
};
```

Comment: What does it mean *not working*?

Comment: It doesn't log the response in console.

Comment: What is logged in the console instead? Did you call `getDashboardService`? Does any other message appear in the console if you would add `console.log('something')` in this function?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the provided there is no visible issue with a code. You should provide more code but I can give you something to check. First, check if you have this inside your android manifest:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` 
then you should check if there are any CORS issues and also check if you are importing the correct axios package and check URL you are connecting to as well.

Comment: This isn't issue with internet permission. If you enable the debug mode, that case it's creating problem, however, if the debug mode is off this works fine.